# How controller inheritance works in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I am trying to inheritance some properties from main controller but is not working as I expected.When I change values for data in main controller it update values for subcontroller too . Once I focus on subcontroller then is start working as I excepted .I have a counter in main controller which I want to store number enter by user but when user enter count for main controller it changes count of subcontroller .Why its update child Class.
How inheritance works in angularjs

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
        <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <label>Count for main controller</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="count">
            <div ng-controller="subController">
            <label> count for sub controller</label>    

                <input type="text" ng-model="count">

            </div>
            {{count}}
        </div>

    </body>


<script>
var myapp=angular.module('myapp',[]);
myapp.controller('MainController',function($scope){
    $scope.count=0;
    //other properties
});

myapp.controller('subController',function($scope){

    //other properties  
});
</script>
```

Comment: try to use controllerAs Controller Syntax , https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers

Comment: Prototypal inheritance comes into play, perhaps you could read through this to get a better grasp of what's going on: [Article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS use prototypical inheritance in Controller ,that's why when change value in base class it will change in child class too. Child is access properties from base class directly.

When we focus on child controller it create  its own copy property and disconnected from property in base class. there is no way to stop this.

How ever we can force base properties to updated as child class update that properties Buy assigning object to $scope rather then properties directly.

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
        <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <label>Count for main controller</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="val.count">
            <div ng-controller="subController">
            <label> count for sub controller</label>    

                <input type="text" ng-model="val.count">

            </div>
            {{val.count}}
        </div>

    </body>


<script>
var myapp=angular.module('myapp',[]);
myapp.controller('MainController',function($scope){
    $scope.val={count:0}
    //other properties
});

myapp.controller('subController',function($scope){

    //other properties  
});
```

Now on updating child property it will update parent property too and will remain connected.